# Need to copy paste to another Workbook if each row in specific column contains "yes"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro, which looks through column "C" and in each Row in column "C" that contains "yes", then the file with the link in "B2" should automatically be opened and the text in "F2" should be copied and pasted as values in the opened file in Range "I2" and afterwards the file should be saved with the new filename which it takes from "H2" and then the file should finally be closed.

Below is the macro i tried, but unsuccessfully.

[Sample File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhE2f.png)

```
Sub Copy()

Dim SWB As Workbook
Dim TWB As Workbook
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim OldFileName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range

Set SWB = ThisWorkbook
Set SWS = SWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

NewFileName = Range("H2").Value
OldFileName = Range("B2").Value

response = MsgBox("Have you reviewed the files? This is a     notification.", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
If response = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

Set rng = Range("A1:Q500")

For Each row In rng.Rows

If (Cells((i + 1), 3).Value) = "yes" Then

On Error Resume Next

With SWS.Range("F2").Copy
End With

Set TWB = Workbooks.Open(OldFileName)
With TWB.Sheets("CFF 12M")
.Range("I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With


TWB.SaveAs filename:=NewFileName

Application.CutCopyMode = False
TWB.Close Savechanges = True

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: VB.NET <> vba and doesnt do macros.  please remove the tag

Comment: okay, what is wrong with you code?

Comment: Take out the `On Error Resume Next` and let us know what (if any) error is thrown, and at what line.

Comment: I try taking out On Error Resume Next , but nothing happens. No errors and no reaction.

Comment: Use <kbd>F8</kbd> key to debug and see where is the issue.

Comment: The issue lies in the following 3 lines of codes:                                                                                                                       'If (Cells((i + 1), 3).Value) = "yes" Then                                                                                                            'End If 'Next